# What race are Pucks?

Tags: carnival-row

In the Amazon original *Carnival Row* there's a race of humanoids with ram horns and hoofs. The dialogue only refers to them as "pucks" which I assume to be an epithet instead of their actual race. In one episode the constables are tracking a suspected murderer and find hoof prints. They deem that they can't be troll prints. As far as I know pucks are the only hoofed humanoid so are they then trolls?

Or is puck the actual name of the race?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pucks is a term for [Faun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faun).

From the section in the [Carnival Row Role Playing Guide](https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Carnival-Row-RPG.pdf) (co-written by the show-creator) describing the different races:

> Fauns
>
> Fauns are digitigrade, with legs similar to horses. Their horns are generally curled but come in all shapes and sizes, largely depending on the region the faun is from. They are robust with strong bones, and their horns can serve as powerful natural weapons. Fauns are also quite hearty and resilient.
>
> Central to faun identity is the nation of Puyan, from which their mysterious religion originates. Natives to the cultural center of Puyan are referred to as Puyoc, which is where the derogatory term “puck” stems from.

Of course, out-of-universe [Puck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puck_(folklore)) is probably a reference to the mythological character Puck, and/or the Shakespeare character based on him, often portrayed as being a faun-like character with horns of some variety or the other, however as Carnival Row takes place in a world that is not quite ours, it had a separate source for the name.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a *satyr* to me:

> noun
>   1.
>   GREEK MYTHOLOGY
>   one of a class of lustful, drunken woodland gods. In Greek art they were represented as a man with a horse's ears and tail, but in Roman representations as a man with a goat's ears, tail, legs, and horns.

[image: Picture of a Satyr]

[Puck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puck_(A_Midsummer_Night%27s_Dream)), a character in Shakespeare's *A Midsummer Night's Dream*, is sometimes portrayed as a satyr, but that is up to the designer, since I don't believe he's explicitly described that way in the play.

[image: Puck from *A Midsummer Night's Dream*]